# Is there a Collection that is suitable for keeping N elements (within size constraints)?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm looking to keep a history of objects representing the result of a process. Currently I built a class around a fixed size array for this and am moving the entire array back one unit (using Array.copyto) to make room for a new value when its added. I'm guessing this is rather inefficient since I'm rewriting the entire array every time I add a value so I was wondering if there is an existing collection type more suited for this?

EDIT: doh, i just figured out i dont need to move the array but just keep a record of where the virtual beginning of the array is.. regardless, question still stands

Comment: You already answered the question yourself: a ring buffer implemented using a fixed size array.

Comment: Give us a piece of code please

Answer (score 0):

@Jake: according to my understanding you are looking to store the history of fixed size (number) of objects. And when this size is exceeding you want to remove oldest entry to add newest entry.

I'll suggest using Queue to store the history.

You can make a method in utility class to append entries to Queue where you can check the size of queue before adding an object.

you can refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are after is a `Stack(Of T)`: *a variable size last-in-first-out (LIFO) collection of instances of the same arbitrary type.*  This fits what most 'history' usages would need.  If you are actually after first-in-first-out then a `Queue(Of T)` is probably what you are after.

One "problem" with these is that you cannot control the capacity making it problematic for cases where you want/need a maximum fixed number of items in the history (mentioned twice in the OP).  It turns out, it is pretty simple to write your own fixed capacity Stack:

```
Public Class StackEx(Of T)

    Private _List As New List(Of T)
    Private Const MIN_CAP As Integer = 8
    Private Const MAX_CAP As Integer = 15000         '?

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(cap As Integer)
        Capacity = cap
    End Sub

    Public Property Capacity() As Boolean

    ' add item to history / stack
    Public Function Push(ByVal item As T) As Integer
        _List.Insert(0, item)

        ' remove old stuff if needed
        If (_List.Count > Capacity) Then
            _List.RemoveAt(_List.Count - 1)
        End If

        Return _List.Count
    End Function

    ' return and remove most recent
    Public Function Pop() As T
        Dim item As T = _List(0)
        _List.RemoveAt(0)
        Return item
    End Function

    Public Function Peek() As T
        Return _List(0)
    End Function
End Class
```

You can add Contains, IndexOf, Count, ToArray etc as needed just using the underlying `List(of T)` functions (some of these do not exist in the NET Stack class).  A Property to turn on/off the Capacity limit can also be added.  For a fixed capacity `Queue`, you could do the same thing modifying where you `Pop` from (Enqueue) and `Push` to (Dequeue).